# Same image loaded for Parent and Child in SAPUI5 treetable

Tags: sapui5, treetable

Hi I am using SAPUI5 [tree table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/TreeTable.html).
Now my model is something like this

```
         {
                name: "BookingCollection",
                //operations:operations,
                0:{
                    name: "Query",
                    dropDown: false,
                    img: "op"      <-- Should LOAD SECOND but the get request for it is never fired
                },
                1: {
                    name: "Read",
                    dropDown: false,
                    img: "op"
                },
                2: {
                    name: "Create",
                    dropDown: false,
                    img: "op"
                },
                3: {
                    name: "Update",
                    dropDown: false,
                    img: "op"
                },
                4: {
                    name: "Delete",
                    dropDown: false,
                    img: "op"
                },
                dropDown: true,
                img: "et"     <-- GETS LOADED FIRST AS IT IS PARENT
            }
```

I am binding on the key '**img**' for the ImageControl :

```
 var nodeImage = new sap.ui.commons.Image();

    nodeImage.bindProperty("src", {
                        path:"img",
                        formatter:function (value) {

                            switch (value) {
                                case 'et':
                                    return "images/gv/et.png";

                                case 'op':
                                    return "images/gv/opr.gif"
                            }
                        },
                        mode: sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay

                });
```

Now the problem is that parents image is shown for the child as well even though the formatter returns the correct path for child image.

Is it because of some binding issue? Why is the child element like Query,Read etc also referring to parent's image?

Comment: can you share more of your code or setup a jsbin? I think it will be easier to help you in this way.

Comment: I was using tree table inside my custom control after using vertical layout as an aggregation and pushing tree table inside vertical layout the events were properly propagated and correct images were being loaded.